# Schema design for inheritance strategy Table Per Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

I am trying to design a database schema so that it is applicable for the `Hibernate's` `Table Per Class` inheritance strategy. So, I will not let Hibernate to generate the tables, instead I need to design them myself in `Liqibase` but in such way that Hibernate can use them with that strategy.

My entity classes should look like this.

**Vehicle.java**

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Vehicle {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String brand;

}
```

**Car.java**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private String oil;

}
```

**Bike.java**

```
@Entity
public class Bike extends Vehicle {

    private String frame;

}
```

Now, I know that that this strategy means that all the fields are in all tables, but I am not sure about two things.

1) Do I need to include the ID in the derived tables?

2) Do I even need a Vehicle table in the DB, since it will actually never be used as an entity (rather just an abstract class)?

I'd appreciate if someone could clear that for me.

Comment: Do you *have* to use table-per-[concrete-]class?  Hibernate supports it, but some other persistence providers don't (support is optional), and it tends generally to be poor performing relative to the alternatives.

Comment: Why are the `oil` property of `Car` and the `frame` property of `Bike` duplicated in `Vehicle`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I left those properties by mistake, I edited the post now. What do you mean it's poor performing? On a large database it should perform better than the JOIN strategy, no? In terms of speed performance, that is. In my case, speed performance is outweighs the memory performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I know that [the table-per-concrete-class] strategy means that all the fields are in
>   all tables,

Well no, you seem to be confused.  With `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`, each concrete entity class `E` maps to a table that contains columns corresponding to all the fields of `E`, including inherited ones, *but not including fields of entities that are not superclasses of `E`*.

This is to be contrasted with `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`, in which all entity types in a whole inheritance hierarchy map to the same table, which then necessarily contains a column for each property of each entity in the hierarchy (without duplicating inherited fields).

Note also that it is odd that your `Vehicle` entity contains fields with the same names as fields of its subclasses.  Java fields are not polymorphic, so this is unlikely to be what you want.  It's certainly unnecessary.

> but I am not sure about two things.
>
> 1) Do I need to include the ID in the derived tables?

Supposing that you stick with `TABLE_PER_CLASS`, yes, each entity table needs to provide a column for each persistent property of the corresponding entity class, including those inherited from superclasses.  That includes `id`.

> 2) Do I even need a Vehicle table in the DB, since it will actually
>   never be used as an entity (rather just an abstract class)?

Not if you actually declare it `abstract`, but if you leave it concrete, then yes, you need a table for it.  And that makes sense, because in that case you could have `Vehicle` entities that are neither `Car`s nor `Bike`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited my post. I left the 'oil' and 'frame' properties in 'Vehicle' by mistake. Basically what you're saying is I don't need to define a table for the abstract class. But should I define the ID in the abstract class entity, or in the derived entities, or both?

Comment: Because, I'd like the ID to be unique across all tables, ie. no 'Car' and 'Bike' pair should have the same ID.

Comment: @wesleyy, if `Vehicle` is defined as an `@Entity`, even if it is abstract, then it needs an `@Id`, and that ID needs to uniquely identify all instances, regardless of concrete class.  The other answer points out that if you use autogenerated IDs, then that precludes the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy.  But since you're writing the schema yourself instead of letting Hibernate generate it, it's up to *you* to choose one of the alternatives (`SEQUENCE` or `TABLE`) and implement it.  Which are workable may depend on the underlying database.

Comment: @wesleyy, that ID-generation issue happens to be another of the drawbacks of `TABLE_PER_CLASS`, by the way.  Neither of the other two inheritance strategies is affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate schema generation tool should be able to generate your schema if you annotate your entities correctly.

In this case Vehicle table which be generated since your entity class is concrete. You need to define the class as abstract.

All the fields defined in the superclass (including the @Id) will be copied in the corresponding child class tables. There is a limitation though regarding id auto generation. You cannot use the table per class inheritance strategy with the GenerationType.IDENTITY strategy since the generated keys should be unique across all tables. Identity creates unique ids per table

Make sure the Generation.AUTO strategy does not map to the IDENTITY strategy for your RDBMS (You can specify a strategy explicitly eg GenerationType.TABLE to override the default)